# iOS and Android Code Comparison

Tags: android, ios

I have trouble finding the apt title for this question, but basically I was wondering if anyone in the community can recommend me a resource that compares similar aspects of iOS programming with Android. The reason being, is that I am currently an iOS developer, and it will help in my learning of Android faster if I can understand similar conventions in Android.

For example, I have realized that Activity in Android works very similarly to View Controllers in iOS. Another example would be onCreate in Android seems to work similarly to viewDidLoad in iOS.

Are there any websites that provides this comparison? I've search extensively on Google but only found generic search results pertaining to the competition between the rival platforms.

I apologize in advance if this is the wrong community to post this question.

Comment: I suggest you to learn android from scratch as they are so different, learning by comparison is not the best way.

Comment: It would be better for you to start coding a small app in android and then you can compare the same to Ios and bit by bit you will know the similarities and the differences of the both.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the advice. I'm actually learning Android from scratch using Big Nerd Ranch Android programming. However, I found that I could understand the concepts a lot better that helps in my memory retention when I see the similarities across the 2 platforms. Naturally, I am well aware of the key differences between the platforms as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book might help:
[Migrating to Android for iOS Developers](http://www.apress.com/mobile/android/9781484200117)

Though I haven't read it myself, and it is still in alpha.